# Multiple roles in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks

My browser has multiple roles

1. Employer
2. Agency
3. Admin If we perform certain action on one account then it reflects on other. Example - If Employer creates a job then it reflects on Agency account. How to write test cases for this in selenium java?

Comment: What you have tried so far , show us first ? your code trials , error trace if any

Comment: I have not written any code yet for this. I want to know the appropriate approach.

Comment: what is the approach here , you should follow some tutorials. SO is not the right place to ask these kind of question.

Comment: Please suggest some tutorial links for this.

Comment: You can follow this : https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in as an admin
2. Do the action
3. Log in as the agency.
4. Verify the reflection

if you are looking for selenium tutorials.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/index.htm

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-tutorial/

Comment: They are not officials. Though you can refer them , if you want to have minimal knowledge

Answer (score 0):

you can execute this all 3 Users using using parallel execution in selenium.

1. TCEmployerTest.java
   -Login method
   -Logout method
2. TCAgencyTest.java
   -Login method
   -Logout method
3. TCAdminTest.java
   -Login method
   -Logout method

create a Testng xml file. (right click project > TestNG > Convert To TestNG.

open the testng.xml
add parallel="tests"

for reference:
https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html